# An intersection of sums of spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck on this seemingly simple linear algebra question:

Let $V$ be a vector space of infinite dimension, let $B \subset V$ be a basis, and let $W \subseteq V$ be a subspace.

Do we have \begin{equation}\bigcap \limits_{F \subset B \ \text{finite}} W+\operatorname{Vect}(B\setminus F) = W\ ?\end{equation}

(where $\operatorname{Vect}(X)$ is the subspace of $V$ generated by a subset $X$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b_0 \in B$. Note that $\{b_0 + b \mid b \in B \setminus \{b_0\}\}$ is a linearly independent set and let $W$ be its span. Then $b_0 \in W + \operatorname{Vect} (B \setminus F)$ for each finite $F \subset B$ but $b_0 \notin W$.

If $W$ is finite-dimensional the equality does hold (obviously $W \subseteq \bigcap (W + \dots)$). If $v$ is in the intersection then choose a finite $F \subset B$ such that $W \cup \{v\} \subset \operatorname{Vect}(F)$. Now write $v = w + v'$ with $w \in W$ and $v' \in \operatorname{Vect}(B \setminus F)$.  Since $B$ is a basis, $v' =  0$, so $v = w \in W$.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for this nice answer!